# 'rails new' throwing Sqlite errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite, bundler

Apologies if this is a duplicate--I've searched a fair bit and haven't been able to find the exact same issue listed that I can tell.

I'm setting up Ruby and Rails on a new dev machine--running Linux Mint--and I've successfully installed Ruby, ruby-dev, Rails, and Sqlite with the package manager. However, every time I try to run `rails new`, it gets as far as `bundle install --local` and then throws the following error:

```
run  bundle install --local
Could not find gem 'sqlite3' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
run  bundle exec spring binstub --all
bundler: command not found: spring
Install missing gem executables with `bundle install`
```

I am, however, certain that I've installed Sqlite. I tried `gem install sqlite3`, but that fails on the grounds that I don't have Ruby development tools installed--but I *do*. So I'm now massively confused ...

I've used Rails before but it's been a while, and I'm not super familiar with Linux, so please assume I need maximum handholding when answering--apologies for that!

Comment: Did you installed ruby with sudo commad? Also are you using rbenv or other ruby version manger?

Comment: Show your Gemfile :)

Comment: why it runs `run  bundle install --local` rather than `run  bundle install`? that makes bundler not connecting rubygems.org and try to find the gem only in vendor/cache

Comment: Have you added `gem 'sqlite3'` to your `Gemfile`?

Comment: @nuaky I installed Ruby through Mint's package manager.

Comment: @Miro Sorry if I'm missing something, but since this is literally the start of the project, I don't have a Gemfile yet.

Comment: @kevinluo201 I don't know why--that's just what the Rails command is doing.

Comment: @Elizabeth OK, so maybe try this steps: 1) `gem install bundler` and after that 2) `bundle install` or just `bundle`

Comment: @Miro Thanks--suggested step 1 was fine, but ```bundle install``` throws ```Could not locate Gemfile```. Am I supposed to have manually created a Gemfile?

Comment: @Elizabeth Gemfile is created with the project so maybe you accidentally deleted it? Is it new project or you have some your own code into it?

Comment: @Miro Entirely new--this is all literally happening during the ```rails new``` command.

Comment: @Elizabeth OK, but when you use this commands in the console, are you in the main directory of project? You must remember that you have to be in the same directory as `Gemfile`. Are you? :)

Comment: @Miro Yes--I'm in a directory one down from root called Sites. If I run ```rails new [projectname]```, I get the can't-find-SQLite error. But at that point there's literally no Gemfile to add it to.

Comment: @Elizabeth When you are in main directory of your project - how many and what files you see?

Comment: @Miro I don't have a main project directory yet, because it's failing on the command that generates the directory--am I missing something here? Sorry if I'm being obtuse--appreciate the help!

Comment: Which version of Ruby and Rails your have? Check it: `ruby -v` and `rails -v`

Comment: @Miro Ruby 2.5.1, Rails 4.2.10

Comment: Try to install for example `Rails 5.2.3`